# Populating a FilteringSelect datastore from an onChange event

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, dojo

I'm trying to bind an `onChange` event of one `FilteringSelect` to populate another `FilteringSelect`.

```
// View
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('filterselect1'), 'onChange', function () {
        dijit.byId('filterselect2').store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(
            { url: "/test/autocomplete/id/" + dijit.byId("filterselect1").value }
        );
    });
});
```

The JSON is generated from what I can tell correctly from a Zend Action Controller using a `autoCompleteDojo` helper.

```
// Action Controller
public function autocompleteAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $select = $this->_table->select()
                           ->from($this->_table, array('id','description'))
                           ->where('id=?',$id);

    $data = new Zend_Dojo_Data('id', $this->_table->fetchAll($select)->toArray(), 'description');

    $this->_helper->autoCompleteDojo($data);
}
```

I receive the JSON from the remote datastore correctly, but it does not populate the second `FilteringSelect`. Is there something else I need to do to push the JSON onto the `FilteringSelect`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't believe this was causing the problem, but the whole issue boiled down to the fact that it appears that a dojo ItemFileReadStore *REQUIRES* the label property of the JSON to be "name". In the end this is all that it required to wire them together.

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {

    dijit.byId('filtering_select_2').store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({url: '/site/url'});

    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('filtering_select_1'), 'onChange', function (val) {
        dijit.byId('filtering_select_2').query.property_1 = val || "*";
    });
});
```

UPDATE: The property within Zend form has been fixed as of ZF 1.8.4

Comment: Actually, all you have to do is set the searchAttr on the control to make it work. You can either add it to the HTML (searchAttr="description") or in the JS (filteringSelect2.searchAttr = "description").

Comment: You really should make this comment an answer as it really has significant value to the question now, and I'd love to give it an up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Try console.log() in the event to see if it is launched. Changing the store should work, however for other widgets like grid you have also to call refreshing methods.

Comment: An odd effect; the onChange event does fire, but the call the remote datastore doesn't happen until the filterseletc2 is actvated via some event like onClick or keydown.